# 500 Internal server error while using jquery ajax to upload and send file to server

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html, excel

I am trying to have import functionality in my project which allows import of excel sheets only. I want to upload the file and then send it to the server for parsing. I am using ajax jquery to send the file to the server. But I get 500 Internal Server error.
  I have a main form say Form1 and a nested form say Form2. The upload functionality is in Form2. The code is as follows:

```
<form action = @routes.SignUp.uploadFile method="post" id ="upfile">
<input name="file" type="file" id="filename"/>
<input type="button" value="Upload" id="uploadfile"/>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
        var file;        
        $('#filename').change(function(){
         file = this.files[0];
         var name = file.name;
         var size = file.size;
         var fup = document.getElementById('filename');
         var fileName = fup.value;
         var type = fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);
         if(type =="xls" || type=="xlsx")
         {
            return true;
         }
         else
         {
            alert("Upload Excel files only");
            return false;
         }
        });

        $('#uploadfile').click(function(){
        var formData = new FormData($('form')[0]);
             $.ajax({
             url: '@routes.SignUp.uploadFile',
             type: 'POST',
             xhr: function() {  // Custom XMLHttpRequest
             var myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
             if(myXhr.upload){ // Check if upload property exists
                myXhr.upload.addEventListener('progress',progressHandlingFunction, false); // For handling the progress of the upload
             }
             return myXhr;
             },
             //Ajax events
             //beforeSend: beforeSendHandler,
             success:function(){
             alert("completeHandler");
             },
             //error: errorHandler,
             // Form data
             data: formData,
             //Options to tell jQuery not to process data or worry about content-type.
             cache: false,
             contentType: false,
             processData: false
             });

        });
        function progressHandlingFunction(e){
if(e.lengthComputable){
    $('#progress').attr({value:e.loaded,max:e.total});
}
```

}

Can someone please help??

Comment: Check the error logs on the server to see what's happening. The issue is with the server not with the client. Make sure you have uploads enabled, upload size and timeouts are set to values that allow the upload of files of your sizes.

Comment: I think that you might need to set the `Content-Type` header with `multipart/form-data`